# Настраиваемое через админку меню из страниц приложений и статических страниц

Tags: python, django

В проекте есть несколько приложений с их страницами и приложение для создания статических страниц (URL-ы генерятся автоматически). У некоторых страниц есть категории, т. е. дополнительный URL к основному.

В данный момент меню сайта реализовано так, что сначала идут пункты страниц приложений (порядок определен прямо в шаблоне), а затем идут пункты статических страниц, которые генерятся автоматически.

Чтобы изменить порядок, или хуже - сделать так, чтобы какая-то статическая страница была первой по порядку, приходится идти на костыли типа сравнивать URL страницы (прямо в коде шаблона).

---

Вопрос: Может есть какие-нибудь готовые решения? Чтобы можно было настраивать меню через админку, и при этом для каждого пункта меню выбирать: это страница приложения или статическая страница? Или это как-то можно сделать своими руками?

P. S. Давно уже ломаю голову над этой проблемой, но ничего путного пока не придумал.

Comment: а почему бы не добавить в модель поле, например `Order` и задавать в нём порядок вывода страниц? Если я, конечно, правильно понял задание.

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук С сортировкой проблем нет. Суть вопроса в том, чтобы для каждого пункта меню выбрать чья это страница: приложения или это просто статичная страница?

Comment: А помечать в админке, какая это страница - не вариант?

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук Вручную прописывать `blog:index` всякие?

Comment: Тебе нужно определять ещё и какого конкретного приложения - эта странирца? Я думал, просто помечать, страница приложения это, или статическая.

Comment: Как  вариант, можно так прописать. Но, думаю, есть более изящное решение)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, как обычно, сразу после наткнулся на [django-sitetree](https://github.com/idlesign/django-sitetree). Оно позволяет создавать сразу несколько меню, именуемых деревьями сайта. Иронично, но в URL можно вписывать как ссылку приложения в виде `blog:index` (с аргументами тоже можно), так и просто на статичную страницу `/blog/`. Кроме того, поддерживается вложенность и шаблонные теги типа `{{ category.name }}` в качестве названия страницы. И всё это через админку, очень удобно.